# Getting data for a Google Line Chart Visualization from PHP/MySQL

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, json, google-visualization

I'm trying to build a Google Line Chart with MySQL data and while I understand Javascript and how to get data with PHP I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around getting and/or formatting the data in the correct manner.

Right now my table looks like this

```
PERSON  WEEK    PRODUCTION
Bob     2        1
Bob     3        0
Bob     4        0
Bob     5        2
Bob     6        0
Paul    1        0
Paul    2        0
Paul    3        0
Paul    4        2
Paul    5        3
Paul    6        1
Mike    1        0
Mike    2        1
Mike    3        1
Mike    4        4
Mike    5        0
Mike    6        1
Ron     1        1
Ron     3        0
Ron     4        0
Ron     6        0
```

And the graph I essentially want create looks like this
[image: graph visualization]

I was able to make that in the Google Code Playground by manually tweaking the data to look like this

```
WEEK    BOB   PAUL  MIKE    RON
1        0     0      0      1
2        1     0      1      0
3        0     0      1      0
4        0     2      4      0
5        5     3      0      0
6        0     1      1      0
```

So my big question though is how do I do this in an automated fashion?  Obviously I need to either modify my sql query to do the heavy lifting there or massage the data with PHP afterwards, but I'm as lost as a babe in the woods on how to do that.  Further complicating the issue, at least in my eyes, is that in the original data set not every has all the weeks, but needs them to be created and zero'ed out in the final result set.  Also while I'm showing 4 persons it could be 1 to N.

If anyone could point me in the right direction I would be eternally grateful!

**UPDATE**

@asgallant pointed me to this example he had written up - http://jsfiddle.net/asgallant/HkjDe/

I tried implementing the solution he presented, which can be seen here - http://thejspot.ws/qa/table.php

While the first table populates, the second table never displays.  I've tracked it down to this line of code, but I'm not sure what the issue is.

```
var pivotedData = google.visualization.data.group(view, [0], groupColumns);
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: I wrote up an example of how to pivot data in javascript that you can use to do this: http://jsfiddle.net/asgallant/HkjDe/

Comment: @asgallant - thanks for the link.  It looks like exactly what I need, but unfortunately it's not working for me.  Here is the link to my setup of the demo: http://thejspot.ws/qa/table.php - the first tables is displayed, but it never pivots.  This is the line where is dies out 'var pivotedData = google.visualization.data.group(view, [0], groupColumns);' - any thoughts why?

Comment: I suspect that the problem is in your JSON: the numbers are being input as strings.  `{"v":"2"}` should be `{"v":2}`.  If you are using PHP's `json_encode` function to handle the encoding, you can have it parse numbers appropriately by specifying `JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK` as the second parameter to the function call: `json_encode($myData, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK)`.

Comment: @asgallant that was the issue. Thanks!